# Find the inverse of $x^2+6x-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find the inverse of $x^2+6x-2$. My textbook tells me that the solution is $f^-1(x)=\sqrt{x+11}-3$ and I am unable to arrive at this. My working:

$$f(x)=x^2+6x-2$$
Switch x and y, then solve for y:
$$x=y^2+6y-2$$
$$x+2=y^2+6y$$
$$\sqrt{x+2}=y+\sqrt{6y}$$

This is as far as I could get.
Was I on the right path? How can I arrive at $\sqrt{x+11}-3$?

Comment: you could use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$ from $y^2+6y-(2+x)=0$

Comment: Be aware that this function isn't a bijection from $\Bbb{R} $ to the range of $f$, so you'll need to choose which domain you want the inverse on.

Comment: You distribute the square root on the RHS but not LHS. Why ? And what is legit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take square root that way.

$$y^2+6y=x+2$$

$$y^2+6y+9=x+11$$

$$(y+3)^2 =x+11$$

$$y = -3+\sqrt{x+11}$$

To decide the sign when you take square root, you should examine the domain.

Comment: How did you decide to add 9 and 11 to both sides in step 2? It's not 'clicking'?

Comment: Oh you made it a square. I see. It's called completing the square?

Comment: Yes, I did completing the square, you can also use the quadratic formula as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We have $x^2+6x+-2=(x+3)^2-9-2=(x+3)^2-11=y$ implies that $x=\sqrt{y+11}-3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** :$y^2+6y-(x+2)=0$ is a quadratic in y.Hence by quadratic formula you can find y.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x^2+6x-2\iff y+11=x^2+6x+9=(x+3)^2.$$

The rest is yours.